# Dynamic React Routing

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to  react so i need to understand how to dynamically route .
I have a homepage www.abc.com. In that page i have 2 blocks which are rendered dynamically namely **New Deal** and **Recent Product** .Both has **view more** button.

when i click on **view more** button of New Deal i want to go to new page www.abc.com/new-deal.
when i click on **view more** button of Recent Product i want to navigate to www.abc.com/recent-product.

How can i route it dynamically?

Comment: use react router or reach-router and configure your routes and add links to elements

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Route inside you homepage App component. Go through the nested routing [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/2nd-example-nested-routing)

```
const ViewDeal = () => {
  return <strong>Deal Component</strong>;
};

const RecentDeal = () => {
  return <strong>Recent Deal Component</strong>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/viewDeal">View Deal</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/recentDeal">View Recent Deal</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
      <Route path="/viewDeal" component={ViewDeal} />
      <Route path="/recentDeal" component={RecentDeal} />
    </Router>
  );
};

render(<Routes />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ruengc)**

Comment: i want to navigate to new page . and blocks are dynamically generated. if its New Deals.Later if the block changes to Recent deals,then url should be the name of the block. abc.com/recent-deal. In the above example its showing as /viewdeal .

Comment: The above example only contains an example of viewDeals, You will need to add recent-deal in the same fashion. Please check the working demo. Have updated.

Comment: HI. Thank you for the reply. But i have mentioned that the blocks are dynamic. So i have only one View all button which is generated for both the blocks. In the exmaple you have given two separate buttons.In that case this wont work right ? Need your help to figure it out

Comment: Can you create a sandbox, so to understand your requirement properly? Based on my understanding you should have a way so that clicking on view all will take you to respective page.

Comment: Hi Jagrati. I am not able to create a sandbox. But what i want is something we can see in flipkart. In flipkart homepage you can see few blocks..so when i click . The url appended is the name like ( flipkart.com/new-arrival). So i want it to append like that. Tomorrow if it's changed to hot deals. The url should be /home-deals. The name should be appended in browser url.

Comment: Check the updated sandbox. You would need a configuration, so that you can render a particular component